# How to move custom theme to live server?

Tags: shopware

I have created a custom theme (Shopware 6) on my local development server (using the CLI). But how do I proceed to be able to install it on the live server?

Have searched the web for days, but have not found anything.

Kindly, Magnus

Answer (score 1):

The final step of exporting a theme / extension / plugin seems to be missing in the [current official plugin base guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide).

Basically you copy your plugin to the other server, usually creating a zip file of it. So if you have your plugin in `custom/plugins/myplugin`, you can create an archive `myplugin` from that folder.

After copying or unzipping you can refresh, install, and activate plugins using the CLI on the new server or using the admin user interface in your browser.
You can also use a tool like [FroSh plugin uploader](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshPluginUploader) which was originally written for Shopware 5 but also works for Shopware 6 plugins. I also allows to validate your plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I was a bit unsure what to do before zipping my plugin (theme). Got some help from Shopware forum, that I need to run ./psh.phar storefront:build. Now I almost got it working, but get the error "Unable to extract ZIP file."

Answer (score 1):

We keep the custom plugins and themes in `custom/` folder and commit them to a git repository which is based on the Shopware platform repository.

Then we deploy this repository on the live server.